# Randomforest on Bag of words TFIDF/ LSI for Video Recommendation

Tags: feature-selection, python, random-forest

I'm working on the Ted Dataset which has the Name, Description and Transcript of 1000 TED Talks.
My task is to recommend 3 TED Talks to a given video. What I'm doing now is converting the Text to Bag of Words. Applying feature extraction (TFIDF, LSI, LDA, ESA) to reduce dimensions. Taking cosine similarity and then returning the 3 nearest neighbours to that point.

I want to know if I can use Random Forest method for this. Can Random forest classifier perform better than KNN?

Comment: You have not defined any measure of performance. Now you simply return the most similar TED talks by your own similarity criteria. You could use unsupervised RF though and get a different result, which you may or may not prefer. Otherwise to perform supervised learning you would need some kind of empirical targets. E.g. ratio of users choosing to see a suggested link.